# google maps infowindow positioning with polylines

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a map with multiple polylines which I am looking to display infowindow for each line.  I have the infowindow working but it is not positioning to the event click as it should be. Instead, each window displays in the same place.  Can't seem to track down the root of the issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var contentString = "";

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: contentString,
});

function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(30.695895, -97.354080);
  var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 5,
  center: myLatlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

downloadUrl("data.xml", function(data)   {

  var xml = xmlParse(data); 
  var polylines = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("polyline");
  var polylineData = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < polylines.length; i++) {
    polylineData[i] = {id:polylines[i].getAttribute("id"),
                      name:polylines[i].getAttribute("name"),
                      olat:polylines[i].getAttribute("olat"),
                      olng:polylines[i].getAttribute("olng"),
                      dlat:polylines[i].getAttribute("dlat"),
                      dlng:polylines[i].getAttribute("dlng")}
  }

  for (var j = 0; j < polylineData.length; j++) {
    var path = [
      new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(polylineData[j].olat), parseFloat(polylineData[j].olng)),
      new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(polylineData[j].dlat), parseFloat(polylineData[j].dlng))
    ];

    var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: path,
      strokeWeight: 2
    });


    google.maps.event.addListener(polyline, 'click', (function(event,index){
      return function(){
        infowindow.content = '<div class="infobox" style="width:280px;"><span class="name">' + polylineData[index].name + '</span></div>';
        var point = event.latLng;
        infowindow.setPosition(point);
        infowindow.open(map);
      };

    })(event,j));

    polyline.setMap(map);
  }

});

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

XML data looks like this:

```
<polylines>
    <polyline id="176" name="Line Name" olat="53.545204" olng="-113.369492" dlat="53.545204" dlng="-113.369492"/>
</polylines>
```

I have read some similar posts but none of the answers have worked in this case thus far.  Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), a sample of the data in data.xml would be helpful to reproduce your issue.  You probably don't want function closure on `event`, I would suggest fixing the location of the infowindow to the polyline (either one end, the other end, or the center), but it is hard to tell what would work best without an example of a polyline.

Comment: [working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GenericMapBrowser.asp?filename=flights090427.xml) My (well actually [Mike Williams'](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/)) XML format, not yours)

Comment: I've added a sample of the xml data.  Thanks for the example, I am looking to do something similar albeit on a simpler level

Comment: What does downloadUrl/xmlParse look like?

Comment: Your sample polyline has zero length.

Comment: I am using the downloadxml.js script to parse the file... which I believe you (and Mike Williams) are familiar with

Comment: yes that particular line is a point - others are lines with length,  bad example on my part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`event` must be the argument passed to the returned function:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(polyline, 'click', (function(index){
//_________________________________________________________^:the index of the item
  return function(event){
//________________^:the event
    infowindow.content = '<div class="infobox" style="width:280px;"><span class="name">' + polylineData[index].name + '</span></div>';
    var point = event.latLng;
    infowindow.setPosition(point);
    infowindow.open(map);
  };

})(j));
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick - had a feeling it was something simple.